# Some issue when get html source code from internet

Tags: c#

I wanna fetch the html source to analyze the stock information, so I use the following 
sample code to get html data by c# , while I compile it and run, the return value parameter *result* gets a **string value** equal to:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id='submit_form' name='submit_form' method='post'
          action='http://pchome.syspower.com.tw/stock/sto0/ock2/sid2404.html'>
      <input type='hidden' name='is_check' value='1' />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('submit_form').submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Not exact, but very similar. I've indented the data a little to make it readable)

I wanna get the the price data such as 29.15$ or each stock number like 29.20$-->364, 29.15$->174, but there isn't any data in the return value.

Could someone give me some suggestion to solve this issue? Thank you very much:)

```
string urlAddress = "http://pchome.syspower.com.tw/stock/sto0/ock2/sid2404.html";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
    myRequest.Method= "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse =myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string result =sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

Comment: Trying to directly parse result HTML sounds like a bad idea in the first place...

Comment: try http://www.visualwebripper.com/ it might be easier

Comment: They are probably using AJAX calls to update the site after the initial HTML scaffolding has been downloaded. Also note that typically you're not allowed to do this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website automatically redirects each time you visit the page. In order to get around this, you need to submit the hidden field as specified in the page's source. I just tested this and it works:

```cs
string urlAddress = "http://pchome.syspower.com.tw/stock/sto0/ock2/sid2404.html";
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 10;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("is_check=1"), 0, 10);
requestStream.Close();
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
response.Close();
```

All the stock data is stored in the page source so you can parse it using regular expressions.